# PHP - Remove Number Prefix

Tags: php

I'm trying to have PHP remove 1.2. style number prefixes from a string. The main issue I have is when there is meant to be a number there. So basically, it needs to strip all numbers and dots until there is a space or a non-numeric character.

e.g. The following should be returned:

1.2. Hello => Hello

1.2 Hello => Hello

1.2. 123 Hello => 123 Hello

1.2 123 Hello => 123 Hello

1. Hello => Hello

1.2.Hello => Hello

1.Hello => Hello

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: Please add some code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for that with the limit option set to 1.

```
$output = preg_replace("/([1-9\.]*)/", "", $input_lines,1);
```

Comment: Your pattern may work wrong for text like this: `Hello 123`

Comment: True, I assumed there is always a prepended number.

Comment: Thank you, you're a star...all working well :) It does work for "Hello 123"

Comment: Glad it works. You can upvote answers to show they were useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '1.2. Hello';
$text = preg_replace('/^[\d.]+/', '', $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: Check with this case : 1.2 123 Hello => 123 Hello

Answer (score 0):

For this simple case you may use [ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php):

```
ltrim(ltrim('1.2. 123 Hello', '0..9.')); // string(9) "123 Hello"
```

The inner call strips all numbers and dots. The outer call strips any leftover whitespace.